# Difference between ultrasonic transmitter sensor and ultrasonic receiver sensor?

Tags: sensor, transmitter, receiver

What is the difference between ultrasonic transmitter sensor and ultrasonic receiver sensor?
Can an ultrasonic receiver sensor be used as an ultrasonic transmitter sensor or vice versa?

Comment: There are many different types of ultrasonic transmitters/receivers. It would help if you linked datasheets of some specific units.

Comment: A good answer on a relevant question: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/309156<br>
And a detailed explanation from Olin Lathrop: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/309161

Answer (score 4):

A transmitter is optimized for, or might be optimized for transmitting.

A receiver is optimized for, or might be optimized for receiving.

Some transmitters can also receive.

Some receivers can also transmit.

There are also many transceivers (transmitter and receiver), you find these in the bumpers of many cars (park assist) for example.

Comment: Many times even if there are separate transmitter and receiver they are near identical devices.  The TX may have a more robust piezo element to handle higher power and the receiver might have a lighterweight one to offer lower mass and damping offering more receiver gain.  Often having separate parts is done to simplify (separate) the electronic coupling even if identical transducers are used.