# What is this part? Is it a speaker?

Tags: identification

I found it in my parts bin.
I can't find anything about it when I Google on the number on the back.

Not visible on the picture but behind the net it looks like a speaker.

Am my assumption that this is a speaker correct?

[image][image]

Comment: Probably an electret microphone

Comment: ... or an ultrasonic transducer, 40kHz, the (R)eceiver optimised one.

Comment: is it like this? https://robu.in/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/hc-sr04_ultrasonic_sensor_distance_measuring_module_1_.jpg

Comment: @jsotola that looks very similar. But this is only one.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks to me like a common ultrasound transducer.  The "40R" may indicate the intended frequency is 40 kHz, and that this is the receiver, not the transmitter.

I've seen ultrasound transducers that look just like that.

For example, here is a snippet of the datasheet of a SensComp 40LR12 ultrasound receiver:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps even this specific one: https://www.microphonestore.co.uk/product/5586329/MZMUST40R/Ultrasonic-ceramic-cartridge-dia-16-mm-x-12-mm ("UST-40R").

Comment: It does seem to be this. But is there any way I can find out what it is? Can I use the multimeter or something?

Comment: @And: A multimeter won't tell you much.  Maybe you can dig around and find which manufacturers print "40R" on the bottom.  Otherwise, you just assume the specs of units of similar construction and size will be similar, and get a good idea from looking at a couple of datasheets.

Comment: @Andreas have a scope and signal gen?  Drive it with sine with a series resistor (perhaps 1k,) then sweep the frequency. Across the device, if you see a dip centered at 40KHz, then it's a typical ultrasonic transducer (seen in burglar alarms and "bat listener" devices.)  Also:https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/254555/, the T and R have two resonant freqs for different Z at 40KHz

Comment: @wbeaty I don't have either of those. But it actually doesn't matter what it is, I was looking for a speaker 8 ohm. I guess I just toss this back in the bin again. I did however find a speaker from an old cell phone, not sure it's 8 ohm though. But I will try it out. The multimeter should be able to measure that right?

Comment: We'll wait for the next person to find it and post wondering what it is.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like a common electret microphone:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electret_microphone

You find these in all sorts of toys, phones, appliances, etc. nowadays so I am not surprised that you have one in your bin.